# Is it possible to fit interaction terms manually in GAM model

Tags: python, interaction, generalized-additive-model, mgcv

I wonder if it's possible to manually fit interaction terms for non-linear predictors in GAM model. 
Something generically equivalent to R `mgcv` package :

```
gam(y ~ s(x, by = z) + s(w, k)) + x + z + w + k
```

I *have to* use `python` for the GAM model for prediction purpose. For now there's no interaction term option available in the library.
I am also curious how the interaction term $f(x)z$ and $f(w,k)$ are fitted and if I could naively pre-process the interaction terms, e.g. create a product term of w*k like in linear regression (of course not correct) or any other ways.
The goal of this practice is not significance testing so the parameter estimate for each term is not as important.
I found a similar post [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/272329/gam-model-and-interactions-between-nonparametric-terms-additive-interactions-a) but no answers.

I'd really appreciate someone can shed some light for this question.

Update with one example(I can't test it in python so I used R) :

```
set.seed(123)
x = rnorm(5000, 0.5, 0.4)
w = rnorm(5000, 4, 1.2)
b= rbinom(5000,1,0.2)
y=  1.2*x**2 + 1.2*w +x*w + x*b
z=w*x
g=x*b

library(mgcv)

mod1= gam(y~s(x)+w+s(x,w))
mod2= gam(y~s(x)+w+s(z))
plot(mod1$fitted.values, mod2$fitted.values)

mod3 =gam(y~w + s(w, by = b))
mod4 = gam(y~w+ s(g))
plot(mod3$fitted.values, mod4$fitted.values)
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. You can always manually create the product terms, $u = wk$ and input it as a linear feature in the model, so that the GAM finds the optimal $f(u)$ to fit the data.

Comment: Please see updated post for details.

Comment: @user2816711 you made a mistake there. `g` should be `g = w*b` instead of `g = x*b`, in which case the two models (`mod3` and `mod4` yield the same results, but only because `b` is binary, wouldn't work for otherwise. Models `mod1` and `mod2` only yield similar results because you simulated the interaction effect as linear `x*w`, wouldn't work otherwise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can fit interaction with tensor product terms in python now using pyGAM (versions >= 0.6.0)

for example, if you want an interaction between feaures 0 and 1 you can do

```
from pygam import LinearGAM, te
from pygam.datasets import toy_interaction

X, y = toy_interaction()

gam = LinearGAM(te(0,1)).fit(X, y)
```

i cannot think of a way to pre-process data to produce an equivalent model.